# Removing duplicate objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to remove duplicate objects from an array. I've tried both using a set, and using a for loop. Why does neither of these solutions work?

```
var array = [
  {"title": "Assistant"},
  {"month": "July"},
  {"event": "Holiday"},
  {"title": "Assistant"}
];

var set = new Set(array);
console.log(set);

let newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(newArray.indexOf(array[i]) === -1){
    newArray.push(array[i])
  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7uzucqj5/

Comment: Because the first element and the array and the last ARE DIFFERENT OBJECTS. They are completely different with different places in memory allocated for them. Just because they have the same keys and values doesn't mean they're equal. They need to also have the same reference.

Comment: how does an object qualify as a `duplicate object`? Should both key and value be same?

Comment: That was my assumption, that if two objects had the same key value pairs, that they would be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this, Also works if you have same element in different order.

```js
var arr = [
  {"title": "Assistant","name":"myname"},
  {"month": "July"},
  {"event": "Holiday"},
  {"name":"myname","title": "Assistant"}
];
var newArr = [];
var temp = [];
for(var i in arr){
  var str = JSON.stringify(sort(arr[i]));
  if(temp.indexOf(str)){
    temp.push(str);
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

function sort(unordered){
const ordered = {};
Object.keys(unordered).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  ordered[key] = unordered[key];
});
return ordered;
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}) != JSON.stringify({b:2, a:1})` :)

Comment: I wanted to say it wouldn't work if you didn't sort the keys

Comment: yeah, I noticed after

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stringified object as value for the set and filter with it.

It may not work with object who have more than one property with a different order.

```js
var array = [{ title: "Assistant" }, { month: "July" }, { event: "Holiday" }, { title: "Assistant"  }],
    hash = new Set,
    unique = array.filter(o => !hash.has(JSON.stringify(o)) && hash.add(JSON.stringify(o)));
  
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will not work for his case where the "duplicate" object has keys in a different order

Comment: @bluehipy, right, that is the pitfall what i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient way to do this using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqWith), would be :

```
_.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual);
```

This will compare the objects inside array to look for duplicates and return an array of unique objects.
It's tested and can be viewed on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uzucqj5/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Set` and `map()` function in simple way

```js
var array = [
  {"title": "Assistant"},
  {"month": "July"},
  {"event": "Holiday"},
  {"title": "Assistant"}
];
let output4 = [...new Set(array.map(s => JSON.stringify(s)))]
    .map(s => JSON.parse(s));
console.log(output4);
```